# Is a unified theory encompassing all types of physics possible?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, theory-of-everything, unified-theories

According to the cGh cube, a theory of everything should incorporate quantum mechanics, relativity and gravity. It should also include the other 3 forces to be unified to a single force. However, how can a quantum theory of everything describe everything at classical levels(size of the atom to the size of the universe)? Is there a formula to convert quantum equations to classical ones?

Comment: There are all sorts of models in physics. To say that there are only "three types" is a statement of profound ignorance of the history of science and its development to its current state of affairs. It is more helpful to think in terms of physical regimes, in which certain models are better suited to explain experiments than others. Philosophically, this is a principle known as complimentarity.

Comment: The first two figures of https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9702155 provide a nice overview. Then again, there's also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TOyt2fOAOkg

Comment: @ConnorBehan these figures are much too coarse. A better starting point would be the PhySH scheme: https://physh.aps.org/browse?facetIds=Research%2520Areas

Comment: "Relativity" is neither distinct from "classical," nor distinct from "quantum." It overlaps both.

Comment: There is only two types of physics: good physics and bad physics;-)

Answer (score 2):

QFT is actually the relativistic theory of quantum fields. Before this, there was the relativistic theory of QM, that is of particles, but this proved problematic in rendering it consistent. The main problem being here its not possible to get a relativistic theory of particles where particle number is conserved. In QFT, particle number is not conserved, so we get the creation and annihilation of particles.

The usual theory that is described in QFT books is actually perturbative QFT. This is because we can actually do calculations with it. Its usually said that it doesn't have a rigorous development but there are not very well known formalisms that do describe it rigourously, for example through Kevin Costello's factorisation algebras.

What comes after QFT is quantum gravity. There are two main programmes for this: string theory and loop quantum gravity. Both of them can describe the phenomena that most physicists think of paradigmatic of quantum gravity - Hawking radiation.

Nevertheless, there is not yet the consensus that a unified theory has yet been achieved.